# Binary to Decimal Converter Issues

Tags: javascript, html, binary

I have been trying to troubleshoot this code, but nothing is coming to mind. The expected result is as follows...

1. I enter a binary number of 6 digits or less into the textbox.
2. I press the "Convert" button.
3. A short paragraph will display the decimal equivalent of the binary number.

```js
var BinIN = document.getElementById("binaryInput").value;
let DecOUT = 0;

function compute() {
  if ((BinIN.charAt(0) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 1);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(1) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 2);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(2) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 3);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(3) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 4);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(4) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 5);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(5) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 6);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(6) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 7);
  }

  if ((BinIN.charAt(7) = 1)) {
    DecOUT += Math.pow(2, BinIN.length - 8);
  }

  document.getElementById("DecimalOutput").innerHTML = DecOUT;
}
```

```html
<label for="binaryInput">Binary</label><br />

<input type="text" id="binaryInput" name="binaryInput" value="0" /><br />

<button onclick="compute()">Convert</button>

<p id="DecimalOutput"></p>
```

Comment: None of your `if()` are doing what you think they should do because `=` is not a comparison operator ... use `===`

Comment: Besides that your algorithm is flawed

Comment: On your above code, you should change `=` operator to `==` and change value 1 to "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smaller algo would be this:

```js
function compute() {
  var BinIN = document.getElementById("binaryInput").value;
  document.getElementById("DecimalOutput").innerHTML = parseInt(BinIN, 2);
}
```

```html
<label for="binaryInput">Binary</label><br />

<input type="text" id="binaryInput" name="binaryInput" value="0" /><br />

<button onclick="compute()">Convert</button>

<p id="DecimalOutput"></p>
```